# Connect to SAP HANA DB using jdbc and Kerberos Delegation

Tags: java, jdbc, single-sign-on, hana, kerberos-delegation

Is it possible to connect to SAP HANA DB from my java application using jdbc and Kerberos Delegation?

Now I can create jdbc connection to SAP HANA DB without input db login and password, using only windows login.
For this I set Kerberos External ID for db user in SAP HANA Administration Console (user1@domain_name) and use property "NativeAuthentification=true" when I create jdbc connection. 
Then I login to Windows by user1 and run my application, and I can connect to SAP HANA DB and select data.

But I need login to Windows on client computer, run my client java application, connect to my application server, application server must connect to SAP HANA DB with permissions of connected user and select data, granted to this user.

In client java application I got kerberos token using waffle-jna library, then I use it to connect to my application server using Spring Security (it works), but I can not create jdbc connection to SAP HANA DB using this token. I can not use Kerberos Delegation.

Any one know something about Kerberos Delegation in SAP HANA DB via jdbc? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Alexander, did you find any solution on this?
We are doing the exact thing and not able to figure out how to proceed.

Comment: Yes, I did. Property "Native Authentication=true" was a wrong way. I configured HANA to work via jdbc and Kerberos Delegation using gss api. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/
Today I will try to briefly describe what settings I made and what code I used.

Comment: Thanks, will wait for your reply.

Comment: @Alexander
How did you manage to create a jdbc connection to SAP HANA DB without input db login and password (from client machine to HANA)? 
I'm specifically looking for the set up required and the JDBC connection properties / string. Did you need any .conf file set up in the client's machine?

Sorry to bring up an old question again, but I can't seem to find any success stories other than yours.

Comment: In my case JDBC connection properties was on server side
      properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:sap://10.0.0.121:31015");
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HANAColumnStoreDialect");
and other prorerties. 
However, maybe I misunderstood your question, English is not my native language..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem using GSS API. Now i briefly describe settings and code, which works in my environment

**1. Environment**

Client java application run on Windows 7 (java SE version 8, swing), application server run on Windows 2012 r2 (java 8, tomcat or jetty, on glassfish did not work), sap hana db run on linux. 
Windows user, which will connect to hana db and Windows user, which run application server, is in one windows domain (active directory).

**2. Configuration windows domain**

Was created spn and .keytab file in windows domain controller

**3. Configuration hana**

There is good Guide "HowTo_HANA_SSO_Kerberos_v1.7.1.pdf" 
Was created db user in hana with external ID user@windowsdomain (account name from windows active directory)
There is good python script for configure hana for kerberos and check configuration. We got this script via sap hana support site.

**4. Client configuration**

windows registry key allowtgtsessionkey must be set to true

On client were files 
login.conf

```
com.sun.security.jgss.login {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useTicketCache=true
doNotPrompt=true
debug=true;
};

com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useTicketCache=true 
principal="saphanauser"
debug=true;
};
```

and krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = DOMAINNAME.NEW
    forwardable = true
    clockskew = 3000
    default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts rc4-hmac
    default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts rc4-hmac
    permitted_enctypes  = aes256-cts aes128-cts rc4-hmac
[realms]
        DOMAINNAME.NEW = {
                kdc = KDCSERVERNAME
        default_domain = DOMAINNAME.NEW
        }
[domain_realm]
        .domainname.new = DOMAINNAME.NEW
        domainname.new = DOMAINNAME.NEW
```

**5. Server configuration**

On server were files

login.conf

```
com.sun.security.jgss.login {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useTicketCache=true
doNotPrompt=true
debug=true;
};

com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useTicketCache=true 
debug=true;
};

com.sun.security.jgss.accept {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
storeKey=true
keyTab="C:/krb/keytab/krb5_hdb.keytab"
useKeyTab=true
realm="DOMAINNAME.NEW"
principal="HDB/LINUX.DOMAINNAME.NEW"
isInitiator=false
debug=true;
};
```

and krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = DOMAINNAME.NEW
    forwardable = true
    default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts rc4-hmac
    default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts rc4-hmac
    permitted_enctypes  = aes256-cts aes128-cts rc4-hmac
[realms]
        DOMAINNAME.NEW = {
                kdc = KDCSERVERNAME
        default_domain = DOMAINNAME.NEW
        }

[domain_realm]
        .domainname.new = DOMAINNAME.NEW
        domainname.new = DOMAINNAME.NEW
```

**6. Client code**

Getting token for send it to application server

```
public static byte[] getTokenGss() throws GSSException {

        String spnName = "spn_name";

        String oidValue= "1.2.840.113554.1.2.2"; // KERBEROS_MECH_OID
        String userLogin = System.getProperty("user.name");
        Oid mechOid = new Oid(oidValue);

        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");

        Path directoryConf = "C:\\client\\krb";
        String pathToGssConfigFile = directoryConf.resolve("login.conf").toString();
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", pathToGssConfigFile);
        String pathToKrb5ConfigFile = directoryConf.resolve("krb5.conf").toString();
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", pathToKrb5ConfigFile);

        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");

        GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();
        GSSName gssUserName = manager.createName(userLogin, GSSName.NT_USER_NAME, mechOid);

        logger.debug("before createCredential");
        GSSCredential clientGssCreds =
                manager.createCredential(gssUserName.canonicalize(mechOid), GSSCredential.INDEFINITE_LIFETIME, mechOid,
                                         GSSCredential.INITIATE_ONLY);

        byte[] token = new byte[0];

        // create target server SPN
        GSSName gssServerName = manager.createName(spnName, GSSName.NT_USER_NAME);
        logger.debug("before createContext");

        GSSContext clientContext = manager.createContext(gssServerName.canonicalize(mechOid), mechOid, clientGssCreds,
                                                         GSSContext.DEFAULT_LIFETIME);

        // optional enable GSS credential delegation
        clientContext.requestCredDeleg(true);
        token = clientContext.initSecContext(token, 0, token.length);
        return token;

    }
```

**7. Server code**

Creating hibernate EntityManagerFactory using token from client

```
private EntityManagerFactory createEntNamagerFactoryViaKerberos(byte[] inToken)
            throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "C:\\krb\\gsslogin\\login.conf");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "C:\\krb\\krb5.conf");

        Oid mechOid = new Oid("1.2.840.113554.1.2.2");
        GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();

        //first obtain it's own credentials...
        GSSCredential myCred =
                manager.createCredential(null, GSSCredential.DEFAULT_LIFETIME, mechOid, GSSCredential.ACCEPT_ONLY);

        //...and create a context for this credentials...
        GSSContext context = manager.createContext(myCred);

        //...then use that context to authenticate the calling peer by reading his token
        byte[] tokenForPeer = context.acceptSecContext(inToken, 0, inToken.length);

        if (!context.isEstablished()) {
            throw new Exception("Context not established!");
        }

        //...then obtain information from the context
        logger.debug("Clientcipal is " + context.getSrcName());
        logger.debug("Servercipal is " + context.getTargName());

        if (context.getCredDelegState()) {
            logger.debug("Then is delegatable.");
        } else {
            logger.debug("Then is NOT delegatable");
        }

        GSSCredential clientCr = context.getDelegCred();
        Subject s = GSSUtil.createSubject(clientCr.getName(), clientCr);
        KerberosActionCreateEmf kerberosAction = new KerberosActionCreateEmf();
        kerberosAction.unicalEntFactoryName = "kerb" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        Subject.doAs(s, kerberosAction);
        EntityManagerFactory emf = kerberosAction.emf;
        return emf;

    }



    class KerberosActionCreateEmf implements PrivilegedExceptionAction {

        public EntityManagerFactory emf;

        public String modelName;
        public String unicalEntFactoryName;

        @Override
        public Object run() throws Exception {

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver");
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:sap://10.0.0.121:31015");
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HANAColumnStoreDialect");

            // do not use login and pass, use kerberos delegation (token)
            //properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", login);
            //properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", pass);

            properties.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", "default_schema");
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", model_manager_hibernate_show_sql);
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name", unicalEntFactoryName);
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "false");
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_soft_references", "1");
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_strong_references", "1");

            properties.setProperty("hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle", "3");
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize", "20");
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout", "600000");
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.hikari.AutoCommit", "false");
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.hikari.poolName", unicalEntFactoryName);
            properties.setProperty("hibernate.hikari.connectionTimeout", "1800000");

            EntityManagerFactory newEntityManagerFactory =
                    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnitName", properties);

            emf = newEntityManagerFactory;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**8. useful links**

http://thejavamonkey.blogspot.com/2008/04/clientserver-hello-world-in-kerberos.html
https://dmdaa.wordpress.com/category/java/jgss/
https://dmdaa.wordpress.com/2010/03/13/kerberos-setup-and-jaas-configuration-for-running-sun-jgss-tutorial-against-ad/
http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~weijun/special/krb5winguide-2/raw_files/new/kwin

Comment: Thank you very much Alex for the comprehensive answer.
In code sample given in #7, I submitted the incoming token to jdbc call, but I got the authentication exception from SAP HANA.
My token comes from the browser. Still I will verify again, because token is just a token, and it should be irrespective of from where it is coming- from browser or from a java code.

Comment: Perhaps the use of a token from the browser has its own specific. I used only token received from java.

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried above code,  GSSCredential clientCr = context.getDelegCred(); is working. however, when i perform Subject s = GSSUtil.createSubject(clientCr.getName(), clientCr); , subject only contains name and not the credentials. Do you have any idea about why this is happening? I've asked the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56320386/kerberos-delegation-gssutil-createsubject-returns-subject-with-principal-name-o